# Use a socket on several pages

Tags: php, sockets, session

I am working on a php application that is sending data through a socket. On my main page I establish the connexion with the client, and I would like to send data from another page of the web app.. but I don't know how to do that.

I am currently trying to use $_SESSION variables [close your eyes this is not pretty]

**main page :**

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3);
$_SESSION['mySocket'] = socket_accept($socket) ;
socket_read($_SESSION['mySocket'], 1024);
```

**second page :**

```
socket_write($_SESSION['mySocket'], "myText", 6) ;
```

But it does not work because `$_SESSION['mySocket']` is not a ressource anymore on the second page (just `0`)... If I use the write command on the main page it works fine, but not on another page. Do you have any idea why ? Is there a cleaner way to do that than using $_SESSION variables (surely there is) ?

**EDIT : maybe my real question is : when does a socket connexion close (if I didn't ask for it) ?**

Comment: if you want use persistent soket you can use [pfsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets are really only for CLI programming, and there you don't have a `$_SESSION` object available.

Additionally, it doesn't make sense that you will want to share the socket in the first place, because the socket is a means of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). If you pass the socket handle between scripts, then what use is the socket anyway?

If you are trying to communicate between one script and the other, you will want to have the first script listen on a socket (as you did), and then create an infinite loop where the script listens for requests.

In the second script, you connect to the same socket, but don't listen to it.

So I guess what you actually want to do, is to have a third file `config.php`:

And in both scripts use

You will want to expand this later to make the `$host` configurable independently, if you want to communicate between computers on a network.

All in all, this is quite advanced programming and you will need to read a lot more about sockets. If I haven't scared you off enough, you could read up on some example code as it is [shown in the PHP manual](http://php.net/socket_read#79314).